# How to distinct grok filter for similar logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have this to kind of logs for `dhcpack`:

> Jun 30 06:34:18 HOSTNAME dhcpd: DHCPACK to IP (MAC) via eth2
>
> Jun 30 06:34:28 HOSTNAME dhcpd: DHCPACK on IP to MAC via eth2

How can I use `grok`, to use two different matches?
I have these two matches for `dhcpack`, but just use the first:

> ((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*(%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\s*dhcpd\S+\s*(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.*[for|on]
> (%{IPV4:dhcp_client_ip})?.*[from|to]
> (%{COMMONMAC:dhcp_client_mac})?.*via (%{USERNAME:interface}))
>
> ((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*(%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\s*dhcpd\S+\s*(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.*[to]
> (%{IPV4:dhcp_client_ip})?.*via (%{USERNAME:interface}))

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with this:

> filter
>   {
>       grok
>         {
>             match => ["message", "(dhcpd\S+\s*(%{WORD:dhcp_action_test}))"]
>         }
>         if "DHCPINFORM" in [message]
>           {
>              grok
>                {
>                   match => ["message","((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*    (%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\s*dhcpd\S+\s*(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.*[from] (%{IPV4:dhcp_client_ip}))"]
>                }
>           }
>         else if "DHCPDISCOVER" in [message]
>           {
>              grok
>                {
>                   match => ["message","((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*(%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\s*dhcpd\S+\s*(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.*[from] (%{COMMONMAC:dhcp_client_mac})"]
>                }
>           }
>         else
>           {
>               drop {}
>           }
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pulling the common stuff (up to the colon) off first and then processing the more specific stuff with more specific patterns.  Some details [here](http://svops.com/blog/processing-common-event-information-with-grok/).

As shown in [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match), grok{} can take multiple patterns:

```
filter {
  grok { match => { "message" => [
     "Duration: %{NUMBER:duration}",
     "Speed: %{NUMBER:speed}"
  ] } }
}
```

By default, it will stop processing after the first match, but that's configurable.

EDIT:

Based on your other comments, you can also branch based on conditionals:

```
if [myField] == "someValue" {
    grok {
        ...
    }
}
else {
    grok {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case, you're running a comparison ("==") or regexp ("=~") to see if you should run a regexp (grok{}).  Depending on the full business logic, this seems like a waste.

Comment: I want do something like:


           if (dhcp_action == "DHCPINFORM") 
            {
                    ((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*(%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\sdhcpd\S+\s(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.[for|on] (%{IPV4:dhcp_client_ip})?.[from|to] (%{COMMONMAC:dhcp_client_mac})?.*via (%{USERNAME:interface}))
                 }
         else
          {
               ((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*(%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\sdhcpd\S+\s(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.*[to] (%{IPV4:dhcp_client_ip})?.*via (%{USERNAME:interface}))
              }

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I want do something like:

```
In ((%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp})\s*(%{HOSTNAME:hostname})\sdhcpd\S+\s(%{WORD:dhcp_action})?.[for|on] (%{IPV4:dhcp_client_ip})?.[from|to] (%{COMMONMAC:dhcp_client_mac})?.*via (%{USERNAME:interface}))
```

get just dhcp_action and use if statement, like:

```
 if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
         ......
 } else {
         ......
 }
```

It's possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use conditions, though you may not want to.  I've updated my original answer.